# PHP ⎼ Do not round numbers

Tags: php, rounding

I have to put 2 id-s together from `$_POST` then I want to explode them, example:

> My id-s are 38 and 310. I made the id-s to this id = "38.310" in my html file.

After `$_POST` I want to explode the id-s:

```
$id=$_POST['id'];

echo($id);  // Gives 38.31
$new_id = explode(".", $id);

echo($new_id[0]); // Gives 38
echo($new_id[1]); // Gives 31
```

Is the a way to get these id-s not rounded?

I need the `38` and the `310`! The id `310` can be also `1003000` ...

EDIT:

```
function dostuff(document, message, id, action) {
        var eingabe;
        eingabe = confirm(message);
        if (eingabe === true) {
            document.msgform.action.value = action;
            document.msgform.id.value = id;
            document.msgform.submit();
        } else {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

LINK

```
<a href="#" onclick="dostuff(document, 'MESSAGE',<?php echo($row['vID']);?>.<?php echo($row['id']);?>,'FITTER_fitter_repaired');" class="button small red" >ACTION</a>
```

$row['vID'] = 38

$row['ID'] = 310

and my submit looks like this

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="msgform" action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="action"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="id"/>
</form>
```

Comment: you should show how you submit the post value. There is some casting before submitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the function `dostuff` is doing, but Javascript is the evil one. Put quotes around the values. In this way there is no casting involved and it gets posted as string.

```
<a href="#" 
onclick="dostuff(document, 'MESSAGE', '<?php echo($row['vID']);?>.<?php echo($row['id']);?>','FITTER_fitter_repaired');" class="button small red" >ACTION</a>
                                      ^                                                    ^
```

EDIT:

But I also think that Lee's solution would be better. Just make 2 input fields and fill them in your `dostuff` function. You could also give id's to the input fields to make it easier to fill.

```
<input id="id1" type="hidden" value="" name="id[]"/>
<input id="id2" type="hidden" value="" name="id[]"/>
```

Comment: damn your right!! thank you! i thought it was a php problem... now i jump behind the train :D

Answer (score 5):

Not 100% sure why your doing that, but why not just use a POST array like

```
id[]=38&id[]=310
```

Comment: + For addressing the root cause.

Comment: can't use this. i become an syntax error! i'm runing a javascript. so i need to add a number :D

Comment: Of course you can, javascript is perfectly able of creating a string of characters... which is all it essentially is (there's nothing magical about POST). Post your JS and someone will show you how.

Answer (score 2):

> is the a way to get these ids not rounded?

There are a few ways, I prefer to cast it to an integer:

```
$id = (int)$_POST['id'];
```

Others ways would be [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) or [`floor()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php).

Comment: this gives me only 38

Comment: ? this seems to be the opposite of what OP asked for

Comment: Yes. I see your root problem. See **Lee**'s answer. My answer is strictly how to not round the values.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you dont understand @Lee answer you could use something other than a `.` as the seperator so PHP does not assume the variable is a number. 
Best not use a coma either as that is the decimal in some countries.

So for example use the dollar sign `id="38$310"

and `$new_id = explode("$", $id);`

Comment: this gives me also a syntaxerror. because im running a javascript and need a number

Comment: @bernte I see no javascript. So thats your next question?